# How to obtain a new access token for a Facebook App

Tags: facebook-oauth

By mistake, I removed my App from my account which of course disabled the access token. I have been following the steps from Facebook's Authentication Doc page to get a new access token and finally had success but to no avail; the access token, actually the several tokens I have generated do not work.

Can someone provide some direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the javascript SDK - this is your best path:

```
    <div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                //you access token is right below
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                console.log('connected and allowed');
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                console.log('connected but not allowed');
                top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_RETURN_URL&scope=user_photos,publish_actions";
            } else {
                // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
                top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_RETURN_URL&scope=user_photos,publish_actions";
            }
        });
    };


</script>
```